# how to zoom and pan imageview images in viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a View pager .
I use Image View in it to display images.
Image is scrolling perfectly but I am not able to pan and zoom the images.
How can i do this?
Is it possible to do using webview? I tried to do but its not zooming correctly. the page zoom but image is not zooming

Comment: About using WebView, try this (Andro Selva's answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758847/pinch-zoom-in-android-for-an-imageview

Answer (score 0):

Android image view does not support pinch and zoom as default.

Use [any custom view supporting pinch and zoom](https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview) or implement yourself using [ScaleGestureDetector](http://android-developers.blogspot.kr/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html).